# Flex Mobile - Highlight Selected Row in Item Renderer

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, itemrenderer

I am building an ItemRenderer in order to display a list of jobs that a company may want to carry out on a building. A user then may click on a job to select it and use add/edit/delete buttons on the parent view.

How would I highlight the selected HGroup in my s:ItemRenderer to allow a user to see which job is currently selected?

```
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="70%">
        <s:DataGroup width="100%" height="100%" 
                     horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" 
                     dataProvider="{Session.EXISTING_JOBS}"
                     >
            <s:layout >
                <s:VerticalLayout />                
            </s:layout>



            <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:ItemRenderer verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" width="100%">                                   

                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[


                                protected function jobSelect_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    // highlight the HGroup here
                                    if(this.selected == true){
                                        jobRow.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor',0x000000);
                                    } else {
                                        jobRow.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor',0xFFFFFF);
                                    }                                       
                                }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>


                        <s:states>
                            <s:State name="normal"/>                            
                        </s:states>
                        <s:HGroup id="jobRow"
                            width="100%" height="50" 
                                  verticalAlign="middle"
                                  click="jobSelect_clickHandler(event)" >                               
                            <s:Label text="{data.id}" 
                                     width="15%" height="50" 
                                     verticalAlign="middle" 
                                     verticalCenter="0"/>       
                            <s:Label text="{data.company}" 
                                     width="35%" height="50"
                                     verticalAlign="middle"
                                     verticalCenter="0"/>
                            <s:Label text="{data.building}" 
                                     width="35%" height="50" 
                                     verticalAlign="middle"
                                     verticalCenter="0"/>   
                            <s:Label text="{data.assets}"
                                     width="15%" height="50"  
                                     verticalAlign="middle"
                                     verticalCenter="0"/>       
                        </s:HGroup>
                    </s:ItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>

        </s:DataGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the itemRenderer in a list; the List class already does this by default.  You can change the value by setting the [selectionColor style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html#styleSummary).

If you really want to change values on the HGroup, you can use the style [contentBackgroundColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/GroupBase.html#style%3acontentBackgroundColor).  You can tell whether your current renderer is the selected item or not by accessing the [selected](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html#selected) property of the itemRenderer instance.

```
    protected function selectJob_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // highlight the HGroup here
        if(this.selected == true){
          hgroupID.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor',0x000000);
        } else {
          hgroupID.setStyle('contentBackgroundColor',0xFFFFFF);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add an ID to the HGroup:

```
<s:HGroup id="hgroupID" 
          width="100%" height="50" 
          verticalAlign="middle"
          click="selectJob_clickHandler(event)" >
```

Comment: This has no effect. Am i missing anything when setting up the the item renderer? I've moved it into the same mxml file now to make it easier to manipulate the data.

New code updated.

Comment: I just needed to set 'selected' to true before highlighting the group. Any idea on how to unselect all the others at the same time, so only one may be selected?

Comment: You should make sure your itemRenderer responds to the dataChange event in order to update it's state based on list selection.  That should refresh it's state when an item is selected and when an item is not selected.

Comment: I have:
<s:ItemRenderer dataChange="selectedJob_dataChangeHandler(event)"
and in script:             protected function selectedJob_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           
          }

Comment: There is something wrong w/ the renderer code that changes styles if using the dataChange will either prevent selection of force everything to be selected.  I'm not sure if I'll have a chance to look deeper.

Comment: This still allows multiple selections and/or prevents selecting any of the items. Is there not a 'reset renderer function' that I can call before the HGroup click or a deselect I can use through bubbling? -- Edit: The dataChange event is never hit, as the data doesn't change, just is used to populate a static field.